# Replace a tag video to img using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, html5-video

I am using PhantomJS 2.0 to get screenshot of some webpage. So in this [page](http://webuser.nl) I have the tag `<video>` of the HTML5. However, I have been reading that PhantomJS does not suport it. So my idea is to replace this tag to a `<img>`. Then, for it I will need to get the size of the video content, create a image element with this size and remove the video.

Remember it needs to be inside the PhantomJS.

I tried it, but not works!

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://webuser.nl', function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {       
    phantom.exit();
  } else {
    page.viewportSize = { width: 1900, height: 1080 }; //these sizes can be others
    page.evaluate(function(){
      var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
      var w = video.clientWidth;
      var h = video.clientHeight;
      console.log("size->" + w + "x" + h);

      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = 'background.png';
      img.width = w;
      img.height = h;

      var source = video.getElementsByTagName("source")[0];

      video.removeChild(source);
      video.appendChild(img);     
    });  
    page.render(relative_path);
    phantom.exit(); 
  }
});
```

In this code, using the console in the browser (Chrome 46.0.24) is works, I resize the windows and the `w` and `h` change, but inside the PhantomJS, independent of the viewport, always is the same size, and I couldn't replace the video to the image.

Does someone have any idea how I could do it or have another idea? 
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah! I fixed the syntax. So the size is `size->381x18 (from line # in "")` independent of the viewport.

Comment: Yeah! Sorry, I just typed wrong. However, do you know something how I can do it? =)

Comment: Someone has any idea?